# simple probability question picking a pen out of 4 and out of 3 colors

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

I have this simple problem which I cannot seem to solve , it is in an introduction to probability chapter.

so we have 4 pens , and 3 colors.. 2 blue , 1 red 1 black we pick them randomly one by one and with no return until we get a black pen EDIT- the question is that we need to write the probability mass function (the simple ones like in those tables) like find all the probabilities for $P(X=i,Y=j)$ hope it is understandable it is hard to translate this

X - counts the number of pens we picked , Y - counts the number of colors

so since we have 4 pens $X∈{{(1,2,3,4)}}$ and 3 colors so $Y∈{(1,2,3)}$

$P(X=1,Y=2)=P(X=1,Y=3)=P(X=2,Y=1)=P(X=2,Y=3)=P(X=3,Y=1)=P(X=4,Y=2)=P(X=4,Y=1)=0$

because these cannot happen.

now I think that I should use Hypergeometric distribution but it only works on some of them..

works on $P(X=3,Y=3)=$ $\frac {{1 \choose 1}*{1 \choose 1}*{2 \choose 1}} {{4 \choose 1}{3 \choose1}}$
I will get $\frac 2{12}$  which is right according to the book

${1 \choose 1}$ for 1 black pen out of 1 , ${1 \choose 1}$ 1 red pen out of 1 , ${2 \choose 1}$ 1 blue out of 2 , and for ${4 \choose 1}{3 \choose1}$ its because we need 1 pen out of 4 and 1 color out of 3 but I am not certain if it worked randomly or not

$P(X=2,Y=2)=$ $\frac {{1 \choose 1}*{1 \choose 1}+{1 \choose 1}*{2 \choose 1}} {{4 \choose 1}{3 \choose1}}$I get $\frac 3{12}$ which is also right according to the book

${1 \choose 1}*{1 \choose 1}$ since we need 2 pens and 2 colors we can have 2 options or 1 black and 1 red which is this option ,and I added ${1 \choose 1}*{2 \choose 1}$ because it can be one of the blue pens.

but this method doesnt work for (atleast for what I tried) on $P(X=1,Y=1)$ , $P(X=3,Y=2)$ and for $P(X=4,Y=3)$.

appreciate any help and tips, please the explanation is more important than actually solving this is just from a random practice book I have and I know that the question is probably very simple for most of the people here but I am new to this topic so I would like to know the approach to this question more than the final answer..
*** the answers for what is left : $P(X=1,Y=1)= \frac 1{4}$ , $P(X=3,Y=2)= \frac 1{12}$  and $P(X=4,Y=3)= \frac 1{4}$
thank you.

EDIT2 - by the end of every $P(X=i,Y=j)$ we will always have a black pen that is why some of them are $P(X=x,Y=y)=0$

EDIT3 - to make it clear for the $P(X=i,Y=j)$ as stated in the question X tells us how many pens were picked until we got the black one and Y is the number of colors picked so for example $P(X=1,Y=1)$ means 1 black pen and 1 color $P(X=2,Y=2)$ means 1 black pen and 1 more pen which we don't know its color , but we do know that we have 2 colors (Y=2 so 1 black and 1 can be red or blue)

Comment: What is the question asking for? If it asks for the probability eventually we get the black pen without returning the probability is obviously 1.

Comment: @cr001 I did an edit hope it is a bit more understandable.. it is hard to translate this

Comment: why do you think $P(X = 2, Y=1) = 0$? There are 2 blue pens

Comment: @P.J. $P(X=2,Y=1)=0 $ is because we need 1 black pen it is not possible to have a black pen and another pen but get only 1 color

Comment: Before any of these details, you need to clarify what is $P(X = i, Y = j)$. It is not clear.

Comment: @MathLover I did as stated above. I will copy X - counts the number of pens we picked , Y - counts the number of colors so for example $P(X=2,Y=2)$ means we have 2 pens because X=2 and 2 colors because Y=2 so you can say it is  $P(X=2∩Y=2)$ EDIT- X=2 means that we picked 2 pens till we got the black one so out of those 2 (X=2) 1 of them is a black pen

Comment: @MathLover please tell me if it is better now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to approach it. I will take a few cases to explain.

First $P(X = 3, Y = 3)$. So the third pen is black and you get pens of all $3$ colors in $3$ picks. I am denoting Black with capital $B$ and Blue with small $b$. So the possibilities are $(R, b, B)$ and $(b,R,B)$.

$P(X=3,Y=3) = \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{4} \times \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{6}$

or you could write it as $P(X=3,Y=3) = \displaystyle \frac{{2 \choose 1}{1 \choose 1}}{4 \choose 2} \times \frac{{1 \choose 1}}{2 \choose 1}$

Not let's take the case of $P(X=1,Y=1)$ that you were getting wrong answer for. The only way to get it is the first one is black out of $4$ pens.

So $P(X=1,Y=1) = \frac{1}{4}$

Next take $P(X=3,Y=2)$. What are the possibilities? Only $(b,b,B)$

So $P(X=3,Y=2) = \frac{2}{4} \times \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{12}$

or you could write it as $P(X=3,Y=2) = \displaystyle \frac{2 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2} \times \frac{1 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1}$

Now for $P(X=4,Y=3)$, possibilities are $(b,b,R,B), (b,R,b,B), (R,b,b,B)$.

So $P(X=4,Y=3) = \displaystyle \frac{3 \choose 3}{4 \choose 3} \times \frac{1 \choose 1}{1 \choose 1} = \frac{1}{4}$.